# JWT with Django Rest Framework not working in production

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

My application uses Django Rest Framework for the APIs and JWT for authenticating the users. Everything was working fine in my local machine. I started having problems after a deployed it to an EC2 instance.

The only things that still work are the login, registration and tokens refresh. That is, when I try to log in, I receive the tokens back from the back-end, which are successfully stored in the local storage; when I try to sign up, the back-end creates the new user; and from time to time the tokens are also successfully updated.

But all the other API calls fail. At the beginning, when I made an API call, I was getting back "401 Unauthorized".

I believe the reason was because Apache wasn't forwarding the Authorization-Headers. So I added "WSGIPassAuthorization On" to the Apache configuration.

Now I am getting "500 Internal Server Error" instead.

As I already said, only API calls to login, tokens refresh and registration are working. For login and tokens refresh, I am using the default "TokenObtainPairView" and "TokenRefreshView".

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView

urlpatterns = [
    path('log-in/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('refresh-token/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

For the registration, this is the view I am using:

```
class CreateUserAPI(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_taken = User.objects.filter(username=request.data['username']).exists()
        if user_taken:
            return Response({'message': 'username already taken'}, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        email_taken = User.objects.filter(email=request.data['email']).exists()
        if email_taken:
            return Response({'message': 'email already taken'}, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is one of the views that doesn't work:

```
class DeckApi(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Deck.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        serializer = DeckSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Comment: Try this, it worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151833/token-authentication-does-not-work-in-production-on-django-rest-framework